# Libration vs. rotation for mass on rotating disc

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation

Hello I have a question about the difference between rotation and libration. In some textbook it is stated that for libration
\begin{equation}
q (t+\tau) = q(t) \\
p (t + \tau) = p(t)
\end{equation} 
with the coordinates $q$, the momentum $p$, time $t$ and period $\tau$. Rotation is given by 
\begin{equation}
p (q + q_0) = p(q)
\end{equation}
Now I am wondering if a mass is fixed on a rotating disc, rotating with a constant angular velocity, then this would be a libration, but I would expect it to be a rotation, since I had the feeling that libration and oscillation should be similar, but this example is not an oscillation.

Comment: I believe rotation is required for libration. For instance, the Moon rotates, librates, and nutates - and probable has other small oscillations.

Comment: And I think of the libration, nutation, etc. as being a result of the mathematical description of the motion being imprecise. For instance, the case of the Moon, Cassin's Laws being imprecise.